# Interpretar tags de html en un string de php o twig

Tags: html

Si tengo un string en php/twig que con tiene tags html

```
<p> hola que tal </p>
```

Como hago para que al cargar la página éste muestre el contenido según los tags en vez de que me lo imprima tal cual con los tags por medio?

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente imprimes el string ejemplo:
codigo:

```
<?php
$miString="<li>prueba 1</li>";
$miString2="<p>Esto es un parrafo</p>";
?>
<html>
<?php echo $miString; echo"</br>"; echo $miString2;?>
</html>
```

**resultado**
[image: resutlado]
Espero te sirva de guia

Comment: Utilizo symfony, y esas variables con tags html vienen de un controlador, y las imprimo en la página con twig y me imprime todo el codigo html como texto plano, en vez de hacer saltos de línea o parrafos me imprime la etiqueta en si

Comment: en ese caso porque no usar asi: {{ mi_variable | raw }}

Comment: @PavloB. te recomiendo revisar esto: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#escaper-extension